# How to show errors for two objects and don't save unless both are valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form for two object User Board

Here is my controller:

```
def create
     @board = Board.new(params[:board])
     @user  = User.new(params[:user])
      respond_to do |format|
        if (@user.save and @board.save)
          format.js {redirect_to some_path}
        else
          format.js {render :action => "new" }
        end
      end
  end
```

I don't want to save either one unless both are valid. And I want to show the error messages for both at one time on the form.

I have tried all types of combinations of '&&' '&' 'and' but they don't give me the result I want. They show the errors of one object while saving the other.

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&&` doesn't work like `&&` in Linux.

You have two alternatives. You can check whether the records are `valid?`, then perform the save.

```
def create
  @board = Board.new(params[:board])
  @user  = User.new(params[:user])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.valid? && @board.valid?
      @user.save!
      @board.save!
      format.js { redirect_to some_path }
    else
      # do something with #errors.
      # You check the existence of errors with
      #   @user.errors.any?
      #   @board.errors.any?
      # and you access the errors with
      #   @user.errors
      #   @board.errors
      format.js { render :action => "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

or if your database supports transactions, use transactions.

```
def create
  @board = Board.new(params[:board])
  @user  = User.new(params[:user])
  respond_to do |format|
    begin
      transaction { @user.save! && @board.save! }
      format.js { redirect_to some_path }
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
      format.js { redirect_to some_path }
    end
  end
end
```

Personally, I would check for `valid?`.

Comment: Thanks Simone I will give that a try. Thank you for your very clear answer. Really helps a NOOB

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the source code of the save method of ActiveRecord you see:

```
def save(options={})
  perform_validations(options) ? super : false
end
```

What you want to do, is running the perform_validations manually before calling save. For this, you can use the valid? method from ActiveResource. You can find the documentation here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F